# How can i get some selected characters in the NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

My NSString Value is

```
 NSString * string = @"A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
```

And i want to develop one method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getAlphabetsBasedOnNumber:2];

}

-(void)getAlphabetsBasedOnNumber :(int)number{

}
```

and I want a result like below:

```
When sending 1 : output:ACEGI(Leave one character).
When Sending 2 : output:ADGJM(Leave two charaters).
```

Comment: You'll have to explain what you want in more detail. How do you get from `1` to `ACEGI` or from `2` to `ADGJM` it doesn't seem to make any logical sense.

Comment: @Fogmeister The "based upon number" would appear to be how many letters to skip.

Comment: @ssmanohar what you do in getAlphabetsBasedOnNumber method? can you please give method implementation code?

Comment: @Rob yeah, I didn't understand to begin with (only being 5 letters long) but then realised :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I understand it now.

Your method should be something like this...

```
- (NSString *)stringFromAlphabetBySkippingLetters:(NSInteger)skip
{
    NSArray *letters = [@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", ...

    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i=0 ; i<letters.count ; i += 1 + skip) {  // 1 + skip because a value of 1 will actually jump two places each time
        [result append:letters[i]];
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is very basic stuff though. You should really have a go at this yourself before resorting to StackOverflow.

As Rob pointed out. If you have a string of comma separated letters then you can convert that to an array by using...

```
NSArray *letters = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: By the way, it might be worth noting that if OP wants to convert his string,`@"A,B,C,..."` string into the array that used here, one can use `NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`. I know you know that, Fogmeister, but for the benefit of the OP...